# Why doesn't my bank ask me why I'm doing a chargeback?

Tags: chargeback, usaa

I've had to do a chargeback a couple of times over the past several years.  In one case the chargeback was approved, in the other case it was denied.  In neither case was I asked for a reason why I was doing the chargeback, nor was I given a chance to explain my reason later (after requesting the chargeback).  Is this normal, and how can a decision be made without my reason being given?

Comment: If they don't ask for a reason, then ISTM that there's either a *technical* or *policy* reason which has nothing to do with justification.  Presumably there was no disputation mechanism?

Answer (score 3):

You should have been prompted to select a reason; but perhaps a generic reason was attached to your dispute without your knowledge, such as that the product/service was not provided.

Here is what it looks like from the merchant's side: They receive a dispute with a reason and are permitted to respond, e.g., as follows:

> Jenny Rosen purchased X from our company on [date] using their Visa
> credit card. The customer agreed to our terms of service and
> authorized this transaction. We shipped the product on [date] to the
> address provided by the customer, and it was delivered on [date].

https://stripe.com/docs/disputes/responding

When your chargeback was denied, you probably could have called your issuer and continued the dispute. But you dropped the matter.

Comment: Thanks.  "Dropped the matter" implies intent.  As far as I remember I wasn't told that I had the option to continue the dispute.  This was LONG ago so details are blurry